# Is necessary to add the resolutions when setting up a favicon?

Tags: html, favicon

here I go: About a week ago I added a favicon to a mobile web site guided thru a tutorial, below you will see my html for the mobile site

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/logos/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/logos/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/logos/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/logos/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
```

now, I am doing the same but in desktop site, I added this

```
<link rel="icon" href="/img/logos/favicon.ico" />
```

and so far is working, but, my question is: for better results do I need to add any kind of resolution tags like `sizes` or something like that? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-link-sizes):

> The `sizes` attribute gives the sizes of icons for visual media. Its
>   value, if present, is merely advisory. User agents may use the value
>   to decide which icon(s) to use if multiple icons are available.

So no, it is not necessary, but may be useful.